# Adding a class to a header when page is loaded from random sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added a class to `<header>` via JS when the page is scrolled like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){

    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(top>=1){
        $("header").addClass('bg-header');
    }

    else
        if($("header").hasClass('bg-header')){
            $("header").removeClass('bg-header');
        }
});
```

The issue is that let's say for example I reload from the footer section of the page (or any other section that is lower than the very top of the page), then the header looses the class, and only gets it back after I scroll down. How would I make it so that it wouldn't loose the added class after reload ?

Comment: Do you mean reload the `window`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches: you can manually fire the scroll event on page load/DOM ready, or simply move all the logic into a function which is called by the scroll event and during page load/DOM ready.

### Solution 1: Call custom function during scroll + page

```
$(function() {

    // Define custom function that contains all the logic
    var customScrollCallback = function() {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top >= 1) {
            $("header").addClass('bg-header');
        } else if ($("header").hasClass('bg-header')) {
            $
        };
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Call custom function during scroll
        customScrollCallback();
    });

    // Call custom function at runtime :) (this is the trick!)
    customScrollCallback();
});
```

### Solution 2: Trigger `scroll` event manually (not ideal)

The reason why this solution is not ideal is because there might be other plugins/scripts on the page that are listening to the `scroll` event. By manually triggering it, you are subverting the default behaviour of the event (because the event is fired without any actual scrolling).

```
$(function() {
    $(window)
    .scroll(function() {

        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top >= 1) {
            $("header").addClass('bg-header');
        } else if ($("header").hasClass('bg-header')) {
            $("header").removeClass('bg-header');
        }
    })
    .trigger('scroll');
});
```